# PostgreSQL JOIN query much slower via Django than on simple Python interpretor

Tags: python, django, postgresql, multiple-databases

here is a topic I have been struggling on for a small while now.

For now, I decided to just limit the requests sizes, but I'd like to know why this happened.
If you can take some time solving this problem, thank you.

**Context**

Here are the models:

```
class Zone(Model):
    zone_id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = CharField(max_length=6, choices=('TypeA', 'TYpeB', 'TypeC'))
    other_fields

class User(Model):
    user_id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    other_fields

class Access(Model):
    access_id= BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    zone_id = BigIntegerField(null=False, empty=False)
    user_id = BigIntegerField(null=False, empty=False)
```

There are two databases. These models are on the one I do not own, I only have USAGE rights.
That is why I did not add *ForeignKeyField*, fearing that Django would want to consider its own automatically generated indexes with this, while that's not how the database has been set.

The database is using PostgreSQL.
The table *Zone* has its indexes `zone_access_id_idx` and `zone_user_id_idx` set already, and that is why, I suppose, when I run the predictable JOIN sql query (detailed below) on psql console and even on simple python, independent script using psycop2, the result is instantaneous.
(the size of zone table is like 100,000 in total, but I filter it to 100 in the query)
(the nb of accesses I want is like 4,000, while the table length is like 40,000,000 in total)

```
class AccessViewset(ModelViewset):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_fields = [f.name for f in User._meta.get_fields()]
        zone_fields = [f.name for f in Zone._meta.get_fields()]
        as = Access.objects.raw(f"""
            SELECT *,
            z.other_fields,
            u.other_fields
            FROM access a
            JOIN zone z
            ON a.zone_id=z.zone_id
            JOIN user u
            ON a.user_id=u.user_id
            WHERE z.type in ('TypeA', 'TypeB')
            LIMIT 500
            """)
        as = list(as)  # this takes 16sec
```

I cannot use `Access.objects.filter(zone__type__in=[])` given what was mentioned before.

**Problem**

When I run this query using django, it takes much much longer (16secs for 500 results).
And when it's via psql, it's instantaneous.

**I tried**

Using `psycopg2.connect().execute()` instead of `Access.objects.raw()`

Adding these to the access model, and faking a migration, did not improve the query

```
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=["zone_id"], name="zone_id_idx", db_tablespace="access_zone_id_idx"),
            models.Index(fields=["user_id"], name="user_id_idx", db_tablespace="access_user_id_idx")
        ]
```

Adding `sshmode='disable'` with the `psycopg2` method.

Comment: "There are two databases" -> how does this relate to the question?  Does the problem occur on both?  Are they identical (especially in terms of data and **indexes**)?

Comment: @snakecharmerb
It **does not relate directly**, I'd say.

It was more about **detailing the context**. So that people understand easily that I use: 
**one** simple database for _django-related tables_, I own this one and can update it using django (and ForeignKeyFields, for instance).

**one** database that _I don't own_, where I only Create and Read rows in some tables.

I hoped this could **trigger some ideas** in the mind of some people that could have had the same environment of work.